# What is better approach to the next DynamoDB usage case?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Imagine the next ordinary situation. We have two types of users - seller and buyer. Seller can create and edit only his offers. Offers can be in two states - active or not.
Buyer can see only active offers of all sellers.
What is a better approach to the task using DynamoDB?
1) Create two DynamoDB instanses, one for active offers and one for not active ones.
In this approach Primary key for both tables:

```
{
  partition: sellerId,
  sort: offerId
}
```

Proc and cons I see:

- (+) receiving own offers for seller is simple (query by partition
  key)
- (+) receiving active offers for buyer is simple (scan corresponding table without conditions)
- (+) we can set different throughput for tables if buyers >> sellers etc
- (-) changing offer state is rather complex (delete and put operations)

2) Create one table with "active" boolean field for an offer object.
Primary key is the same:

```
{
  partition: sellerId,
  sort: offerId
}
```

Index can be:

```
{
  partition: active,
  sort: offerId
}
```

(not sure such index can work effectively)
Proc and cons I see:

- (+) receiving own offers for seller is simple (query by partition
  key)
- (+) changing offer state is simple (put operation)
- (+) using only one table
- (-) receiving active offers for buyer can be complex (scan with condition) or we need additional throughput for index.

So basically the question is whether using index with boolean partition part is ok or not and is there a possibility that one approach leads to a problems with scaling in future and the other one not (maybe I don't see evident drawbacks of any approach)